# HTMLAgilityPack not getting loading html of the webpage

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to Crawl through https://www.adecco.ch/en-us/job-results but i am not able to load html from this page its not loading any getting any thing in html document.

```
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
            var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
            var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();
```

Comment: Did debug the code to inspect what is the value inside `html`? ~You're accessing the website using an `HttpClient` with a default `User-Agent` header, it's very likely you're being treated as a bot (which you are ‍♂️) and not receiving the same content as when you access the page via your browser.~ EDIT: seems like the site is returning the content compressed, and that the `HttpClient` is not decompressing it - maybe because of missing response headers. You'll need to fetch the data as a stream, decompress it, and then load it into the `HtmlDocument`.

Comment: you are right. thank you very much. it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, the content from the site is being sent back compressed and was not being decompressed before you tried loading it, so you were basically loading gibberish. This code should work fine -

```cs
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
// this is the important bit
handler.AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.All;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
var html = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().ToList();
```